# Any free Mind Mapping programs out there?

Tags: mind-mapping

I am looking for a free Mind Mapping package to model a few things.  Any good recommedations?

Comment: I've always liked Pencil and Paper.

Comment: Certainly a solid fall back. Ha!

Comment: Duplicity - http://superuser.com/questions/12038/whats-your-favorite-mind-mapping-software

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like [Mindjet MindManager](http://www.mindjet.com/).  It's not free, but they have a free trial.

Comment: Even though this one will set me back a few bucks, it looks like this might be the best of breed. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 18):

[FreeMind](http://freemind.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) is a good Java-based one - open source, runs on Windows, OS X and Linux.

[image]

Comment: +1 I absolutely love using this tool for mapping out projects. A friend of mine is also using it to write novels.

Comment: The Freemind-fork Freeplane (http://freeplane.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page ) is also worth a look - it has some very interesting features and an active developer community which offers great support! (see: http://superuser.com/a/143509/92184 )

Answer (score 4):

[XMind](http://www.xmind.net/) is a good one.

Answer (score 2):

[Freemind](http://freemind.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page). It runs on Java, so is available on all platforms. It comes included in the Ubuntu repository.

Answer (score 1):

I really like [Cayra](http://cayra.net/).

Comment: Well, looks like their site is down, so if you're still interested you can go to one of the shareware mirror type sites to check it out.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [Freeplane](http://freeplane.sourceforge.net/), an improved version of Freemind. It's free, open source, and Java-based.

[image]

Comment: Freeplane is great and also has a very active developer community with great support for users and their wishes! :-)